# Add validate="required:true" to your html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I want add this to my checkbox: validate="required:true". It results in this:

```
<input type="radio" name="persoonskamer" value="Ja" validate="required:true">
```

But now i have a problem. I used a form cms generator. In my cms, i can not add this direct to the html. I can only give the input a classes. How can i add "validate="required:true" that to my input with javascript.

Thanks for you help guys!

Comment: Idd, it would be more easy to understand :)

Comment: I must have a script. That add validate="required:true to my input radio's.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a radio button (as shown in your code) to be "required": radio buttons are supposed to be used in groups. It doesn't make sense for a checkbox (as mentioned in your description) to be "required": checkboxes let a user enter yes/no or on/off information, so no/off is a valid choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  $('input[name="persoonskamer"]').data('validate', 'required:true');
```

see [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Given this would create an attribute prefixed with 'data', I don't see how this would help.

Comment: @Daedalus no it wouldn't, it would not add any attribute at all

Comment: nice thinking but data doesn't add new attribute, `$('input[name="persoonskamer"]').attr('data-validate', 'required:true');`

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking of another function/method/etc.  However, as @undefined states, it doesn't assist in the OP's problem, so...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="persoonskamer"]').attr('validate', 'required:true')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=persoonskamer]").attr('validate', 'required:true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `required="true"`, here `required` is the attribute, but you have to put that input tag inside of `form` tag